# BY operation on data.table without aggregation

Tags: r, data.table, signal-processing, aggregation, bandpass-filter

I have this issue I would like to share because of the time and trouble it took me to solve.
I have a data.table full of noisy EEG signal that I want to bandpass before plotting.
I placed all participant signal in a R data table along with their many within factors.

My dataset has

- x = time
- y = value
- participant name = p_name
- factor1 and factor 2

The problem is that I would like to directly go from data.table to ggplot2 without having to use 6 imbricated for loops for bandpassing all data in all conditions.

I present here a solution, which consist in 'forgetting' the factor/dimension to parse on. Thus instead of a classical syntax:

```
DF[, m:=mean(value),
    by=.(p_name,factor1,factor2,time))
```

Putting the time factor out of the `by` allows for performing operation on all values across time (in my case frequency filter), returning a list directly applied to each value.

```r
# myfunc(x) returns x filtered for high frequencies
DF[, value_filt:=my_func(value), 
    by=.(p_name,factor1,factor2)) # <- time not in the list
```

Cool fact, the time factor is not even lost in the process.

Is there whether there is a better/faster solution out there ?

## Code for replication

```r
library(data.table)
library(signal)
library(ggplot2)

# Operations on data.table without aggregation

set.seed(1234)
fs = 128 # Hz sampling rate (=length of 1 sec vector)
tseq <- seq(0, .999, by = 1/fs) # t = 128 samples for 1 second 

# For generating signal 128 I created a function 
# that mixes together two sin waves + noise
generate_sig = function(t) {
  x <- sin(rnorm(1)*40*pi*t*.5) + 0.11*rnorm(length(t)) + sin(rnorm(1)*40*pi*t*.5) + 0.31*rnorm(length(t))  # create two random sinusoid+noise
  return(x)
}

# Testing the function
x = generate_sig(tseq)
plot(NA,NA,xlim=c(0,128),ylim=c(-pi,pi),xlab='t',ylab='signal ampitude')
lines(x,col='red')

# Generating a Butterworth filter 
b = butter(2,c(1,15)*(2/fs))

# Applying the filter
xfil = filtfilt(b,x)
# Plotting
lines(xfil,col='black')
```

[image: Generated and Filtered signal]

### Generating data.table data

in a long table with signal for two participants both under factor1 and factor2 conditions

```r
val_pname=c('p1', 'p2')
val_factor1=c('left','right')
val_factor2=c('pain', 'reward', 'sham')
nb_samples = length(tseq)
col_pname = factor(rep(c(val_pname),each=length(val_factor1)*length(val_factor2)*nb_samples))
col_factor1 = factor(rep(rep(c(val_factor1),each=length(val_factor2)*nb_samples),length(val_pname)))
col_factor2 = factor(rep(rep(rep(c(val_factor2),each=nb_samples),length(val_factor1)),length(val_pname)))
col_t= rep(rep(rep(tseq,length(val_factor2)),length(val_factor1)),length(val_pname))
col_values = replicate(length(val_factor2)*length(val_factor1)*length(val_pname),generate_sig(tseq))
col_values = as.numeric(as.list(col_values))
df = data.table(participant=col_pname,factor1=col_factor1,factor2=col_factor2,t=col_t,t_idx=col_t_idx,val=col_values)

# visualizing the whole data table
ggplot(df,aes(x=t, y=val, color=factor1))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(factor2~participant)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

### Now the main issue :

I would like to bandpass signal my data directly from the data table without using for loops. In reality I have about 6 different factors and I want to be able to aggregate them (average)
as I please before doing the bandpass filtering

## ****SOLUTION****

```r
# I managed to work it out this way
df[,val2:=filtfilt(b,val), by=.(participant,factor1,factor2)]
```

There is no aggregation of the time ´t´ factor, thus input table has the same size as output table.

### Visualizing the solution

```r
# visualizing the filtered data table 
ggplot(df,aes(x=t, y=val2, color=factor1))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(factor2~participant)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the original dataset and keeping the time dimension:

```
filtered_df = df[,.(val=filtfilt(b,val),t=t) by=.(participant,factor1,factor2)]
```